# Delphi 7 intraweb 5.1 + Javascript

Tags: javascript, delphi-7

Estou tendo um problema com o `Javascript do Delphi 7 + Google Chrome + qualquer outro navegador mais moderno`. Ele praticamente não funciona, gostaria de saber se isso é normal ou se tem outra forma de usar javascript pra validações, esconder campos e etc.

Já procurei bastante e não achei nada relacionado.

Obs : Estou usando o próprio campo de "Javascript" do form.

Comment: Qual é a versão do intraweb 5.1? No update 5.1.30 houve um acerto na forma de lidar com varios eventos js.